# remove these special characters in this url � https://www.linkedin.com/in/sampreis�

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to removing the special characters before and after the url using php. but not in the actual url, i tried but not able solve this, can you please help me to solve this.

`� https://www.linkedin.com/in/sampreis�`

Comment: Can you provide the codes that you wrote to solve the issue ?

Comment: that's an encoding issue. You want to fix, not remove. You'll be patching your files till the cows come home.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [trim()](http://php.net/trim) function, for example:

```
$string = '� https://www.linkedin.com/in/sampreis�';
$string = trim($string, '�');
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the ascii range to replace all non ascii characters by using regex.

```
var instance = '� https://www.linkedin.com/in/sampreis�'
instance = instance.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g,'')
```

Now the instance would contain only ascii.
As \x00 and \x7F is the hex range (0,127)

Comment: what if JS is disabled? This won't work and is a mere *band-aid*.

Comment: If we could convert the string containing non unicode characters to just contains the ascii range, then language won't be a constraint.